# "Failed to start systemd script to load sep5 driver at boot time" on boot

Tags: boot, systemd

I am currently working on my Master thesis and used Ubuntu on Hyper V for my thesis. But this morning, it suddenly stopped working with this error:

`Failed to start systemd script to load sep5 driver at boot time".` 
Please, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[image: Image of the problem can be seen here]

Comment: With boot logs like this, you can't always infer that the process that created the last log entry is actually the process that is stopping it from completing - however, if the sep5 driver *is* the problem then it appears to be related to Intel VTune performance monitoring - did you change any VM perfmon settings (as described here for example [Enabling performance monitoring components in a virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/performance-monitoring-hardware)) ?